# Delete keys from hash map in perl which matches values from array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key

I would like to use Perl to delete keys from a hash map that match values in a given array.

Example:

Input:

```
   @array = ("apple", "banana" , "cherry")
   %hash = ( '/abc/apple/somestring' => val1,
             '/banana/somestring/somesting' => val2,
             '/xyz/apple/somestring'   => val3,
             '/somestring/somestring/'        => val4,
             '/xyz/somestring/random'        => val2,
           )
```

Output:

```
   %hash = ( '/somestring/somestring/'        => val4,
             '/xyz/somesting/random'        => val2,
           )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

1. For each element in the array, select the matching hash keys

   ```
   for my $elem (@array) {
     my @matching_keys = grep { 0 <= index $_, $elem } keys %hash;
   ```
2. Then, delete the hash entries with the matching keys:

   ```
     delete @hash{@matching_keys};
   }
   ```

The `0 <= index $_, $elem` could also be written as `/\Q$elem/`, if you are optimising for readability instead of speed.

---

Alternatively: build a regex that matches all elems in the array:

```
my $rx = join '|', map quotemeta, @array;
```

Then, select and delete all keys that match this regex:

```
my @matching_keys = grep /$rx/, keys %hash;
delete @hash{@matching_keys};
```

This should be more efficient.

Comment: That works like a charm. I was iterating using foreach loop and it didn't work.

Comment: @amon, bravo! the best tip that I've read today :) delete + slices! bravo!